# PHP initializing variables

Tags: php, session, post

Im watching several php tutorials, and many of them start something like that:

```
<?php
 if(!$_POST['username']){
  ..
  ..
 };
?>
```

or

```
<?php
 $username = $_POST['username'];
  ..
  ..
?>
```

but everytime I visit the page for the first time, it prints an error because $_POST['username'] was not initialize.
How can I I fix this?

thank u

Comment: Take a look at isset() to check if a variable is set.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['username'])){
   ..
   ..
}

?>
```

Comment: thanks for this quick response.

Comment: but I dont understand why when im watching tutorials they dont type isset function. why is that?

Comment: @user2402509 maybe they are putting `@` infront of it like, `@$_POST['username']` will not echo out errors

Comment: @user2402509 for a sample code maybe they skip the isset() part

Comment: Perhaps it's just an introduction. Its assuming that the parameter is going to be posted to the page. It's possible that you may have not correctly posted to the page according to the tutorial and that's why the "isset" is needed.

Comment: no, they are not putting anything, thats why Im asking.

Comment: but I guess they are protected in someway from printing errors on server settings/configs, I guess thats the only way

Comment: Programming is like "water". It's always good to cover all the little cracks where things could slip through. And someone could always tamper with the request and not include the parameters you were expecting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are four main HTTP methods you can use when making a request to a webserver: GET, POST, DELETE, and PUT. With each of these, you can pass variables with your request that PHP allows you to access. For `GET` and `POST`, you can access the variables with the corresponding arrays: `$_GET` & `$_POST`, respectively.

If you've never dealt with HTTP methods before, that's because you don't need to really think about it. This is because of the fact that when you type a URL into your browser and hit go, it uses the `GET` method by default.

So, in this case, what's probably going on is that you're just not making a `POST` request at all when you load your page. And even if you were, you'd need to have the proper `POST` variable defined to access it, which in this example would be `username`.

Since one of the above isn't true, the value of the variable is null. And when you try to access a null value in PHP, the script throws an error (as you've seen). You can change this, but I wouldn't recommend it. I like to know that I'm properly handling my null variables when I write code. But maybe that's just me.

The solution that I recommend, and that others have suggested, is to use the `isset()` function to see if the variable is defined. This will prevent your code from breaking. [Check out the isset documentation for more.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL ~E_NOTICE`

See the documentation on this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

or disable it globally in the php.ini file.

Comment: Certainly errors and notices should not be turned on in a live server. However, on a dev/local machine, this is not the solution - programmers should strive for notice-free code. Turning them off and ignoring them tends to let bugs in, so is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you didn't recieve a value via `POST` (like from a form post). Add an `isset()` validation as others are suggesting. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

use `isset($_POST['username'])`

```
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_POST['username'] is trying to get the 'username' variable which included the the POST http request to your page (think submitting a form).  Normal browsing to a page is an http GET request.

Try using this to avoid issues:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
   ... if POST and includes a username value, do this ...
} else {
   ... otherwise do this stuff ...
}
```

Read me for more info on types HTTP requests: http://techforum4u.com/content.php/229-HTTP-Request-GET-HEAD-POST-PUT-DELETE-OPTION-TRACE